# Iterate raster in R

Tags: r, loops, raster, r-raster

I want to ask about the Raster package.

Is there a way to iterate through raster values, without transforming the values and doing a `for` from 1 to raster max value ?

For example, in the raster bellow I need to do an operation on all "1" values, than operate all "2" values, than all "5" values and finally all "7" values

```
library(raster)

myRaster = raster(matrix(c(1,2,5,1,2,7,5,7,1),3,3))
```

So what I am doing at the moment is transforming that raster into:

```
myRaster = raster(matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,4,3,4,1),3,3))
```

Through a function to normalize the raster values to turn them continuous, but it take a lot of time to run:

```
segmentNormalize <- function(imgSegMask){
    segValues = freq(imgSegMask)[,1]
    segNumber = length(segValues) #number of values in segMask
    if (segNumber != max(segValues)) {
        temp = imgSegMask
        for (i in 1:segNumber){
            print(paste("normalizing ", i, ' of ', segNumber, sep=''))
            imgSegMask[temp == segValues[i]] = i
        }
        rm(temp,i)
    }
    rm(segValues)
    return(imgSegMask)
}
```

Is there a way to loop a raster throught its values ? somethink like `for (i in myRaster){}` that does not need a continuity like

`segNumber = length(freq(imgSegMaskLvl1)[,1])
for (i in 1:segNumber){}`

Comment: 1) You can access the values of a raster using `values(myRaster)` 2) You can build a `for` loop where instead of looping over each value of your raster, you loop over `c(1,2,5,7)` and find where they are located in your vector of raster values using `match` or `which`

Comment: Isn't this myRaster[] <- as.integer(factor(values(myRaster)))

Comment: or `reclassify`